# Import JSON file with dicts of dicts of nested dicts into Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dictionary

I am downloading [a json file from the RKI in Germany](https://services7.arcgis.com/mOBPykOjAyBO2ZKk/arcgis/rest/services/RKI_Landkreisdaten/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=json) (CDC equivalent). It seems to have dictionaries inside dictionaries inside dictionaries. I'm really only interested in the dictionary of data nested in the "features" dictionary. My problem is that each entry in this dictionary is nested with the same key - "attributes". This is what it looks like as text (I have to work with the text because I can't download it directly into python due to proxy issues - grrr.).

```
{"objectIdFieldName":"ObjectId","uniqueIdField":
{"name":"ObjectId","isSystemMaintained":true},
"globalIdFieldName":"","fields":
    [{"name":"AdmUnitId","type":"esriFieldTypeInteger","alias":"AdmUnitId","sqlType":"sqlTypeInteger","domain":null,"defaultValue":null},
...etc...    {"name":"ObjectId","type":"esriFieldTypeOID","alias":"ObjectId","sqlType":"sqlTypeInteger","domain":null,"defaultValue":null}],
"features":
    [{"attributes":{"AdmUnitId":0,"BundeslandId":0,"AnzFall":3741781,"AnzTodesfall":91337,"AnzFallNeu":1456,"AnzTodesfallNeu":18,"AnzFall7T":7178,"AnzGenesen":3638200,"AnzGenesenNeu":700,"AnzAktiv":12300,"AnzAktivNeu":700,"Inz7T":8.6,"ObjectId":1}},
    {"attributes":{"AdmUnitId":1,"BundeslandId":1,"AnzFall":64221,"AnzTodesfall":1628,"AnzFallNeu":35,"AnzTodesfallNeu":1,"AnzFall7T":181,"AnzGenesen":62300,"AnzGenesenNeu":0,"AnzAktiv":300,"AnzAktivNeu":0,"Inz7T":6.2,"ObjectId":2}},
    {"attributes":{"AdmUnitId":2,"BundeslandId":2,"AnzFall":77823,"AnzTodesfall":1603,"AnzFallNeu":50,"AnzTodesfallNeu":0,"AnzFall7T":217,"AnzGenesen":75700,"AnzGenesenNeu":0,"AnzAktiv":500,"AnzAktivNeu":0,"Inz7T":11.7,"ObjectId":3}},
    ...etc
```

When I try to pd.read_json(the_file), I get the Value Error: arrays must all be same length.

If I open as json and load, create a dictionary, I get my dictionary of dictionaries with the dictionary I want. I can almost get there, as below, but I end up with a list of nested dictionaries, where the key is always - "attributes" - which throws the error.

```
with open(r"Q:\AbisF\Covid-19\Lageberichte\Misc\RKI_7Tages.json") as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
# dig down to the data
features = data["features"]
attributes = features["attributes"]   # TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am wondering if I am coming at this the wrong way, of if there is a way to clean up my list (get rid of the attributes level).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `features = data["features"]` is now a `list` of `dict`s.

You can iterate over those:

```py
features = data["features"]
for feature in features:
    attributes = feature["attributes"]
    print(attributes['AdmUnitId'])  # example item in attributes
```

Comment: Ok, super. Then I just need to transpose the results and build my dataframe one row at a time. Groovy thanks.